# Facebook 'Like' Box Issue - Has It Changed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've searched for an answer before posting this (but with no luck).

The Facebook 'Like' box seems to have changed colour without me changing anything on my website.  The theme is set to 'dark', but instead of black, it's displaying as a grey colour, and none of the text updates can be read (as the text is also white/grey).

This seems to be a widespread problem, as other sites I visit are also having issues.  Their like boxes are now grey, and their text cannot be read.  I've also checked the official Facebook Developers page, and have clicked on a preview for the 'Dark' setting, and theirs is also wrong!  It appears grey and the text cannot be read.

Anybody have any ideas how to help me, or ... any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Has the 'On Facebook' text that should appear after the Facebook page name also disappeared ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you cache a wrong facebook css file somehow (from some site) and when you visit other sites with like box you get the cached css. try delete your browser  cache